# InfluxDB - How to get last value and then filter them instead of filter->last

Tags: database, time-series, influxdb

By default，this influxql will execute WHERE clause before LIMIT which behaves like:

1. filter all values
2. find last value

But what can I do if I need to

1. find last value
2. filter these values

   SELECT * FROM temper WHERE temperature > 50 GROUP BY * ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: select * from (select last(temperature) from temper group by *) where last_temperature > 50 can work.